# How to get all the emphasized words from a word without an accent?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a java program that allows me to open the file whose path is in parameter .
All is working when my path like : "C:\telephone1\" AND the folder's name is "telephone1".
But if the folder's name is "téléphone1" (accent) i wan't to find it with my script.
Is it a way to say to the programm : you will have to test :
- telephonne
- télephonne
- téléphonne
- téléphonné
- tèlephonne
- tèlèphonne
- tèlèphonnè
- télèphonne
- ...
Then the script will find it.

?

Comment: So in a nutshell, you want to check every file name permutation with accent? Wouldn't it be easyer to normalize all letters to english alphabet?
Also hat java version you are using? From JDK7++ you got java.nio.Path that can be very helpful.

Comment: This is what I want, I can not ( 20 years of business records )

Comment: Does the accent matters? Are there are two directories with telephone1, but with different accent? What then, process thme both?

Comment: They will not have 2 folders like this : "telephonne" and "téléphonne". What i wan't is in the future stop using accent (so the future folders will be ok) but the old ones need to be open with the same script. When i enter "telephonne" i want is to open me "téléphonne" if exist.

Comment: Can you just wildcard the search? `t?l?phonn?` I'd have to double check doing that in Java, but it's easily done via command line and should port to programming languages.

Comment: If i understand you ask me to replace all my letter witch are succeptible to have an accent by an "?" and it will be ok ? :-P (i think i don't understand ^^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find how to do ! Here is my code in case someone would need it :

```
package ouvrirDossier;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ouvrirDossier{

    private static String path;

    private static final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
            "The only way to close this dialog is by\n"
                    + "pressing one of the following buttons.\n"
                    + "Do you understand?",
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // ON CREE LE CHEMIN D'ACCES AU DOSSIER EN COLLANT TOUT LES BOUS.
        path = "A:\\";
        if(args.length>0){
            int cpt;
            for(cpt = 1;cpt<args.length;cpt++){
                if( cpt == 0)
                    path += args[cpt].replaceAll(";"," ");
                else{
                    if(cpt==1)
                        path += args[cpt].replaceAll(";"," ");
                    else
                        path += "\\"+args[cpt].replaceAll(";"," ");
                }
            }
        }

        //ouvrirAlerte(path);
        // ON REGARDE SI LE DOSSIER EXISTE
        if(ouvrirDossier(path) == false){
            String chemin = "";
            String cheminTemp = "";
            boolean okMatch = false;
            boolean trouve = false;
            String[] etages = path.split("\\\\");
            outerloop:
            for(int a=1; a<etages.length; a++){
                if(trouve == false){
                    chemin = "";
                    cheminTemp = "";
                    for(int b=0; b<a; b++){
                        chemin += etages[b]+"\\";
                    }
                    //System.out.println(chemin);
                    File theDir = new File(chemin);
                    if(!theDir.exists()){
                        for(int b=0; b<a-1; b++){
                            cheminTemp += etages[b]+"\\";
                        }
                        File theDirTemp = new File(cheminTemp);
                        //System.out.println(chemin);
                        //System.out.println(cheminTemp);
                        ArrayList<String> noms = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(theDirTemp.list()));
                        okMatch = false;
                        for(int c=0; c<noms.size(); c++){
                            String regexPattern = Pattern.quote(etages[a-1])
                                     .replace("é", "[eéèêë]")
                                     .replace("u", "[ùúûü]")
                                     .replace("oe", "(oe|œ)")
                                     .replace("a", "[aàâä]");
                            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
                            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(noms.get(c));
                            while(matcher.find()){
                                okMatch = true;
                                etages[a-1] = noms.get(c+1);
                                /*
                                String test = "";
                                for(int e=0; e<etages.length; e++){
                                    test += etages[e]+"\\";
                                }
                                */
                                a--;
                                //System.out.println(test);
                            }
                        }
                        if(!okMatch)
                            break outerloop;
                    }
                    if(a == etages.length-1 && theDir.exists())
                        trouve = true;
                }
            }

            if(trouve){
                ouvrirDossier(chemin);
            }
            else{
                int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                    "Le dossier que vous tentez d'ouvrir ("+path+")ne semble pas exister, voulez vous le créer ?", 
                    "SPB - Le dossier n'existe pas", 
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    if(args[0].equals("T")){
                        new File(path).mkdirs();
                        new File(path+"/Support/Doc").mkdirs();
                        new File(path+"/Support/Dev").mkdirs();
                        // ------------->
                        new File(path).mkdirs();
                        new File(path+"/Courriel").mkdirs();
                            new File(path+"/Courriel/Entrant").mkdirs();
                            new File(path+"/Courriel/Sortant").mkdirs();
                        new File(path+"/Document de Base").mkdirs();
                        new File(path+"/Document Intermediaire").mkdirs();
                        new File(path+"/Donnee").mkdirs();
                            new File(path+"/Donnee/Dsr").mkdirs();
                            new File(path+"/Donnee/Dsi").mkdirs();
                        new File(path+"/Livrable").mkdirs();
                        new File(path+"/Programme").mkdirs();
                    }
                    else if(args[0].equals("P")){
                        new File(path).mkdirs();
                        new File(path+"/Support/Doc").mkdirs();
                        new File(path+"/Support/Dev").mkdirs();
                    }
                    ouvrirDossier(path);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean ouvrirDossier(String chemin){
        File theDir = new File(chemin);
        //System.out.println(chemin);
        if(theDir.exists()){
            // SI OUI ON L'OUVRE
            try{
                Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process process = runTime.exec("explorer "+chemin);
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void ouvrirAlerte(String texte){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SPB");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1270, 100));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(texte);
        frame.add(label1);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public int nbLettre(char lettre, String mot){
        int resultat = 0;
        for(int a=0; a<mot.length(); a++){
            if(mot.substring(a, a+1).equals(lettre)){
                resultat++;
            }
        }
        return resultat;
    }
}
```

Really thanks to [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354251/kyle), [Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen), [xehpuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178016/xehpuk) and all those who helped me :-D

Answer (score 2):

Remove the accents with java.text.Normalizer:

```
s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFKD).replaceAll("\\p{M}", "");
```

This substitutes single code point `é` with `e` plus zero-width acute mark. And then all "combining diacritical marks" are removed.

Normalizing: as there exists different Unicode code point sequences for a single "character."

---

Though two such normalized texts could be compared, a pattern may be made as follows.

```
String regexPattern = Pattern.quote(s)
                 .replace("e", "[eéèê]")
                 .replace("u", "[ùúû]")
                 .replace("oe", "(oe|œ)")
                 ... ;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
```

Comment: If i understand your solution is here to do this : é --> e. What i need is a solution wich will give me this : e --> é|è|ê etc ...

Comment: I agree with the approach here. Normalize all of your data to the simple data set for comparison. However, you wouldn't want to overwrite the path with the normalized name. You would want to use the normalized version to compare for matching, but keep the actual path for navigating and logging purposes.

Comment: This is exactly my problem :'(

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`java.text.Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) with strength [`PRIMARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#PRIMARY) to filter a [`java.nio.file.DirectoryStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CollatorForPaths {
    static final Path root = Paths.get("C:");
    static final Collator collator;

    static {
        collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
        collator.setDecomposition(Collator.CANONICAL_DECOMPOSITION);
        collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    }

    static Path findPath(final String name) throws IOException {
        try (final DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(root, entry -> collator.equals(name, entry.getFileName().toString()))) {
            final Iterator<Path> iterator = stream.iterator();
            return iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(findPath("telephonne"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as i said here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31718240/4787098 I found how to do :-D Have a good day :-P

Comment: @Antoine I think my solution is better regarding both correctness and performance, that's why I've posted it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you had not seen / read. I haven't time to optimize (have to give all soon). It works and that's all I wanted. Still leaves your comment for the next people :-D

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this can definitely be cleaned up and optimized with some regex and a FileFilter. Check out the documentation for [File here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). You could potentially create a `FileFilter` and pass it into the File.listFiles(fileFilter) method to retrieve only the directories for which you want to perform some actions. However, just to create a simple example of an option, I'm doing basic String parsing then creating my File objects manually.

The program below will create a `File` object of our desired directory. It will then look at all the files inside that directory, if there are any. It will create a new `File` object for each child it finds from our original parent directory, if it is a directory, it will then swap all the special e characters to regular e characters and check to see if it starts with `telephonne`, then execute some logic. In this case, just printing out the original directory name.

```
import java.io.*;

public class DirectoryFinder{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        File dir = new File("/Users/myuser/Downloads/sojava/");

        String[] children = dir.list();
        if (children != null && children.length > 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                File file = new File(children[i]);
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    String modifiedName = file.getName().toLowerCase();
                    modifiedName = modifiedName.replaceAll("é", "e");
                    modifiedName = modifiedName.replaceAll("è", "e");
                    if (modifiedName.startsWith("telephonne")) {
//                         do some stuff with file.getName() which is the original file name
                        System.out.println("file.getName(): " + file.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To show you what the program is seeing, here is a listing of the directory where I executed the program.

```
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 kyleandrews  staff  1193 Jul 29 08:55 DirectoryFinder.class
-rw-r--r--  1 kyleandrews  staff   934 Jul 29 08:55 DirectoryFinder.java
drwxr-xr-x  2 kyleandrews  staff    68 Jul 29 08:55 otherdir1
drwxr-xr-x  2 kyleandrews  staff    68 Jul 29 08:55 otherdir2
-rw-r--r--  1 kyleandrews  staff     0 Jul 29 08:55 otherstuff1
-rw-r--r--  1 kyleandrews  staff     0 Jul 29 08:55 otherstuff2
drwxr-xr-x  2 kyleandrews  staff    68 Jul 29 08:36 telephonne
drwxr-xr-x  2 kyleandrews  staff    68 Jul 29 08:36 tèlephonne
drwxr-xr-x  2 kyleandrews  staff    68 Jul 29 08:36 télephonne
drwxr-xr-x  2 kyleandrews  staff    68 Jul 29 08:36 tèlèphonne
drwxr-xr-x  2 kyleandrews  staff    68 Jul 29 08:36 télèphonne
drwxr-xr-x  2 kyleandrews  staff    68 Jul 29 08:36 téléphonne
drwxr-xr-x  2 kyleandrews  staff    68 Jul 29 08:36 tèlèphonnè
drwxr-xr-x  2 kyleandrews  staff    68 Jul 29 08:36 téléphonné
```

I hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time and the work you gave me. I lean on it :-D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can make a dictionary, if the script don't find wihout accent, try to replace "Telephonne" by "Téléphonne" (words saved in a variable).